# Проблемы с jquery/js в консоли и расширении

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Дело такое. Я пишу расширение для скачивания видео с одного сайта. Мне нужно получить `src` элемента с `id="player_html5_api"`. Пытаюсь я значит выполнить мой код (`$("#player_html5_api").attr("src");`) в консоли, а оно мне выдало - `undefined`.

Я залез в HTML код, нашел этот объект, он есть! Попробовал еще раз забить этот код.. И заработало. Пробовал много раз, и с jquery, и с js. Все время одно и тоже - пока на код не посмотришь - пишет `undefined`

Оказывается, в консоли изначально выбран фрейм `top`. При заглядывании в код выбирается фрейм `archive.html`, поэтому начинают работать мои запросы. То есть в консоли достаточно поменять frame, но как быть с расширением?

P.s.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрим в код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробуем заново

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] *Ссылка большая, и я ее обрезал.*

Comment: _Как это исправить?_ - нужно добавить в вопрос больше кода и разметки вокруг

Comment: хотя я догадываюсь в чем может быть проблема: какой frame выбран в консоли когда элемент не находится, и какой - после того, как _посмотрели код_?

Comment: @Grundy Изначально - `top`, потом - `archive.html`. Попробовал изменить в консоли изначально на `archive.html` и заработало. Но как сделать это в расширении?

Comment: а почему свой ответ удалил? он неверный?

Comment: @Grundy да, не помогло почему-то. Все равно undefined

Comment: То есть, проблема на самом деле в том, как из расширения обратиться к html текущей страницы, так?

Comment: @Grundy Теперь да